# Repeatedly change Tkinter window colour to generated colour

Tags: python, tkinter, colors

I have Python code to generate the average colour of the screen as an RGB value **and** a hex code. The code repeats itself through a `while True` loop, and I want to put the instructions to change the window colour at the end of this loop.

I have this code at the moment:

```
from Tkinter import *
from colour import Color

root = Tk()
root.configure(background="grey")
root.geometry("400x400")
root.mainloop()
while True:
    [ COLOUR GENERATING SCRIPT ]
    hexcolour = Color(rgb=(red, green, blue))
    root.configure(background=hexcolour)
```

Can someone please tell me how I can initiate a Tkinter window and then change the colour each time the loop runs?

I'm running Python 2.7 for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `while` loop entirely. Instead, create a function that is what you would do in the loop, and then have that function call itself via `after`. It will then run for the life of the program.

```
from Tkinter import *
from colour import Color

def changeColor():
    [ COLOUR GENERATING SCRIPT ]
    hexcolour = Color(rgb=(red, green, blue))
    root.configure(background=hexcolour)

    # call this function again in one second
    root.after(1000, changeColor)

root = Tk()
root.configure(background="grey")
root.geometry("400x400")

# call it once, it will run forever
changeColor()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've implemented this, but the program just starts a blank CMD window, and no Tkinter window starts up... ([https://i.imgur.com/XAD5I9L.png](https://i.imgur.com/XAD5I9L.png))

Comment: @YasathDias: the only explanation for that would be that `[COLOUR GENERATING SCRIPT]` never finishes. What does that code do?

Comment: You were right, my script was running itself over and over without outputting anything, so after tweaking a few lines, it works perfectly! Thank you so much :)